# Preserve Report Custom Formula values when exporting in Tabular format to Excel

Tags: reporting

I'm trying to create a simple report for all opportunities related to accounts:

Business Account |  Record Count  | Price Sold (sum) | Net Gain (sum) for the time specified when you select the dates.

I have the price sold and net gain fields on the opportunity, but need the report in a tabular format, not grouped by account.

Here's how it looks on printable view when grouped by account: 
[image]

and it should look basic like this by account:

[image]

where the record count adds up the number of opps that were involved in creating the totals.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for help with here - do you just need help reformatting the report? If so, a screenshot of the current report, along with a mockup of what you want the report to look like (in Excel for example) would be useful. Also a link to the documentation which you've no doubt found through a Google search and explanation of which part of the guidance you've been unable to follow would make this easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks @AlexS- I added some pictures to make it more clear

Comment: Thanks Gato so you should be able to go to Customise > click Summary Format and change to Tabular. The record count, which will appear at the bottom of the report automatically, should count the Opportunities if Accounts are the primary object for the report type..here's the [Salesforce Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_changing_format.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Hi @AlexS Yes, but I want to see per account opportunity how many records are included in the net gain - for a matrix or summary its easy as I just add a custom formula that counts the records in the calculation, but I need it exported in tabular format - not grouped by account

Comment: So how many Opportunity's there are per Account?

Comment: So if I run the report for April - May, I want to see the price sold and net gain for all opportunities organized by account - where the record count shows me the number of records used to create those totals.

Comment: @AlexS Basically it's a formatting issue where when running the report and filtering in Excel, there's a bunch of copy and paste rather than just having: 
Account Name  |  Price Sold  | Net Gain  | Record count

Comment: Got it, I'm afraid I'm not aware of a way to do this. I know the formatting from printable view's are really awkward to work with in Excel but I've always just exported the grouped report..